# fallback for FILES in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm using typoscript go get the first file out of a page. This works and is out of the documentation. But the documentation doesn't tell something about a fallback if no files are found.

```
lib.files = FILES
lib.files {
  references {
    table = pages
    fieldName = media
  }
  file =
  begin = 0
  maxItems = 1
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    value = URL: {file:current:publicUrl}
    insertData = 1
  }
}
```

A naive `.if.isNull` failed at the first attpent. Is there a possibilty to define a fallback if the FILES-Object is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Mh,

try to make a second object and check there if lib.files is filled with data.

__

### UNTESTED

```
lib.files = FILES
lib.files {
  references {
    table = pages
    fieldName = media
  }
  file =
  begin = 0
  maxItems = 1
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    value = URL: {file:current:publicUrl}
    insertData = 1
  }
}


lib.fileFallback = COA
lib.fileFallback {

    10 < lib.files

    20 = TEXT
    20 {
        value = Do something
        stdWrap.if.isFalse.cObject < lib.fileFallback.10
    }

}
```

I am using this technique often to slide through pages for slideshow objects.

Let me know, if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [TypoScript Reference stdWrap.ifEmpty](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#ifempty).
In your case the code should look like this

```
lib.files {
  # ....
  stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = IMAGE
  stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject{
    file = fileadmin/.../my_image.png
  }
  # ....
}
```

You can use every cObject you want.
Check out [Content Objects (cObject)](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Index.html)